# ActiveRecord's select not working with outer joins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, spree

In a query, I'd like to select fields from joined tables and get ActiveRecord's relation object.

It does work with inner joins:

```
Spree::Product.joins(:promotion_rules).
  select('spree_promotion_rules.promotion_id').first.promotion_id
# => 1
```

Analogous expression but with outer join ignores specified field for `select` method and
returns original objects:

```
Spree::Product.eager_load(:promotion_rules).
  select('spree_promotion_rules.promotion_id').first.promotion_id
# NoMethodError: undefined method `promotion_id' for #<Spree::Product:0x00000007cd98b0>
```

That's strange, because generated SQL query is correct and should include joined table's field:

```
Spree::Product.eager_load(:promotion_rules).
  select('spree_promotion_rules.promotion_id').to_sql
=> "SELECT spree_promotion_rules.promotion_id, \"spree_products\".\"id\" AS t0_r0, …
    LEFT OUTER JOIN \"spree_promotion_rules\" ON \"spree_promotion_rules\".\"id\" = …"
```

and when passed as raw SQL string it returns the expected result:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
  Spree::Product.eager_load(:promotion_rules).
    select('spree_promotion_rules.promotion_id').to_sql).first['promotion_id']
=> "1"
```

Any idea why `select` does not work with OUTER JOINs and how to "fix" it ?

Comment: I think that ActiveRecord is looking for promotion_id to be an object on Spree::Product, and in fact I'm not sure why the inner join version works.

Comment: I realize your actual question is "why doesn't select" work, but I'm unclear what this line actually does... Isn't it just the same as `PromotionRules.first.id`?

Comment: @LannyBose No. If you see the produced SQL string, it addresses `spree_promotion_rules.promotion_id` column, ie. `Spree::PromotionRule.promotion_id` attribute. `select` limits/sets accessible attributes for query results, with an exception for outer joins as demonstrated.